# Designing a database to house 1 dimensional data

Tags: sql

I have a dataset of trading dates for different exchanges in a csv file. what is the best way to store them in a database? the dataset looks like this...

```
US,DE,JP

20040102,20040102,20040102

20040105,20040105,20040105

20040106,20040106,20040106

...

20210608,20210524,20210715

20210609,20210525,20210716

...
```

Essentially each country has a column of dates their stock exchange is open. Once i have this table created i want to query it to return the number of trading days between two dates on specific exchanges. eg number of trading days between 5/29/2020 and 6/19/2020 in the 'US' is 15.

What's the most efficient way to build the table and what query would i use to get the number of trading days between two dates.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one table with two columns. One column for the country (code) and the other for the day. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE trading_days
             (country varchar(2),
              day date,
              UNIQUE (country,
                      day));
```

(Data types might vary depending on what DBMS you use, you weren't specific on that.)

A query to get the number of trading day for a country in a certain period then could look something like:

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM trading_days
       WHERE day >= <lower bound of period>
             AND day < <upper bound of period plus one day>
             AND country = <country code>;
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't this double the size of the table. I'm trying to stick the rules of normal form and not duplicate data if possible.

Comment: @MattW: What normal form do you think it violates?

Comment: Initially i thought it would violate NF1 because each column has multiple data entries. Then i thought having two columns with country code and dates was duplicating too much data. I guess there is no other way around it unless i have two two tables with a one to many relation between countries and trade dates. Thanks for taking the time to discuss this question.